# What are the major differences between g++ compiler on OSX and Linux?

Tags: makefile, g++, gnu

I have tried to find this but there is not much info on the internet. But there are times when I use premake to make a GNU makefile and there are some link options which are turned on by default on OSX like pthread but not on linux.

If there is a document about it somewhere, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major difference is that unless you have installed a compiler from some other source than XCode, then "g++" on OSX is probably clang:

```
$ path -l g++ gcc
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  23 Dec  6  2014 /opt/local/bin/g++ -> /opt/local/bin/g++-mp-5
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  18176 Jul  8 22:52 /usr/bin/g++
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  23 Dec  6  2014 /opt/local/bin/gcc -> /opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-5
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  18176 Jul  8 22:52 /usr/bin/gcc

$ /usr/bin/g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

$ /usr/bin/gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

That provides different error messages and generally does not return error status for the same warnings that g++ would.

If you installed g++ via MacPorts or homebrew, the *differences* would be whatever is due to differences in the releases of g++.